# Getting this error with py2.7 as well as with py3.7

Tags: html, python-3.x, linux, cgi

Getting this error with py2.7 as well as with py3.7

enter code here

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('10.0.2.15', 41994)  
Traceback (most recent call last):                                         
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread                                                                      
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)                           
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request   
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)                
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__         
    self.handle()                                                          
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/server.py", line 427, in handle            
    self.handle_one_request()                                              
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/server.py", line 415, in handle_one_request
    method()                                                               
  File "/usr/share/set/src/webattack/harvester/harvester.py", line 334, in do_POST                                                                    
    filewrite.write(cgi.escape("PARAM: " + line + "\n"))                   
AttributeError: module 'cgi' has no attribute 'escape'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, you need to add `import html` under `import cgi` and then change `cgi.escape` to `html.escape`. You need to do that in `/usr/share/set/src/webattack/harvester/harvester.py` (for details you can check this link - https://github.com/trustedsec/social-engineer-toolkit/issues/721)

Answer (score 1):

```
import html

html.escape(string_).encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.